Download various salesforce data in their native format
Is there a way to download various salesforce content data in their native format. For ex, if I consider an user record in Salesforce, I should be able to download the email messages related to him/his objects in the native email format (either .eml or .msg). Similarly, I should be able to download the content versions/content documents in their respective native format (pdfs or docx or xlsx). I am okay with exploring the option of using third party programs like python or perl.
Can someone shed some light on such requirements?
